# Using 2 separate plotly (or ggplotly) plots in a tabsetPanel in a shiny app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I am using the `plotly` package to produce two plots styled through their `ggplotly` integration based on a user's inputs. the user accesses each plot by using the tabset panel choice. Unfortunately, in testing, I was not able to use the `plotly` package to produce both graphs without causing my `R` instance to crash.

[UI with normal `ggplot2` functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsXSX.png)

here's the data as suggested by the comments:

```
generationData = read.csv("data/statedata.csv", #"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZbDI31sSKatBoEVKo70TV_A4VwCBHK4pIoCWXB7yfx0/pub?gid=192701245&single=true&output=csv", 
                      header = TRUE) #read csv file
generationDataCleaned = generationData[!(is.null(generationData$Name) | generationData$Name==""), ]

statenames = as.character(generationDataCleaned$Name) 
row.names(generationDataCleaned) = statenames
```

`result()` is a reactive function to calculate the result data frame that the plot uses

```
result <- reactive({
state = input$stateInput
pctCoal = input$Coal / 100
if(state == "") {
  #handle onload
  print("it was blank!")
  state = "Alabama"
  pctCoal = 15 / 100 
  }
     baseCoal_Energy = generationDataCleaned[state, "Coal.Steam.Electric.Generation..MWh."]
     baseNGCC_Energy = generationDataCleaned[state, "NGCC.Electric.Generation..MWh."]

totalEnergy = sum(baseCoal_Energy,
                  baseNGCC_Energy
)
baseEnergy = totalEnergy

coalEnergy_Reduction = (pctCoal) * baseCoal_Energy

newCoal_Energy = (1 - pctCoal) * baseCoal_Energy
newNGCC_Energy =  baseNGCC_Energy + coalEnergy_Reduction

newEnergy = newCoal_Energy + newNGCC_Energy
Energy_Frame <- c(baseEnergy, newEnergy)

#Emissions Rate
baseCoal_CO2_Rate = generationDataCleaned[state, "Coal.Steam.Emission.Rate..lb.MWh."]
baseNGCC_CO2_Rate = generationDataCleaned[state, "NGCC.Emission.Rate..lb.MWh."]

totalCO2_Rate = sum(baseCoal_CO2_Rate,
                    baseNGCC_CO2_Rate
                    )
baseCO2_Rate = totalCO2_Rate

coalCO2_Rate_Reduction = (pctCoal) * baseCoal_CO2_Rate

newCoal_CO2_Rate = (1 - pctCoal) * baseCoal_CO2_Rate

newNGCC_CO2_Rate =  baseNGCC_CO2_Rate + coalEnergy_Reduction * baseNGCC_CO2_Rate / baseNGCC_Energy

newCO2_Rate = newCoal_CO2_Rate + newNGCC_CO2_Rate

CO2_Rate_Frame <- c(baseCO2_Rate, newCO2_Rate) 

#Emissions Mass

baseCoal_CO2_Mass = generationDataCleaned[state, "Coal.Steam.Carbon.Dioxide.Emissions..tons."]
baseNGCC_CO2_Mass = generationDataCleaned[state, "NGCC.Carbon.Dioxide.Emissions..tons."]


totalCO2_Mass = sum(baseCoal_CO2_Mass,
                    baseNGCC_CO2_Mass
                    )
baseCO2_Mass = totalCO2_Mass

coalCO2_Mass_Reduction = (pctCoal) * baseCoal_CO2_Mass

newCoal_CO2_Mass = (1 - pctCoal) * baseCoal_CO2_Mass

newNGCC_CO2_Mass =  baseNGCC_CO2_Mass + coalEnergy_Reduction * baseNGCC_CO2_Mass / baseNGCC_Energy

newCO2_Mass = newCoal_CO2_Mass + newNGCC_CO2_Mass

CO2_Mass_Frame <- c(baseCO2_Mass, newCO2_Mass) 

name_Frame <- c("Base", "New")

result <- data.frame(name_Frame, Energy_Frame, CO2_Rate_Frame, CO2_Mass_Frame)

colnames(result) <- c("Name", "Energy", "Rate", "Mass")

result
})
```

`ui.R`

```
column(8,
       tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                   id = "tabset1",
                   tabPanel("Rate", value = "Rate", plotlyOutput("ratePlot")),
                   tabPanel("Mass", value = "Mass", plotlyOutput("massPlot"))#, plotOutput("massPlot"))
                  )
```

`server.R`

```
output$ratePlot <- renderPlotly({
  gg <- ggplot(result(), aes(x = Name, y = Rate, fill = Name)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 1)
  #gg
  p <- ggplotly(gg)
  p
})

output$massPlot <- renderPlotly({
  gg2 <- ggplot(result(), aes(x = Name, y = Mass, fill = Name)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 1)
  #gg2
  p2 <- ggplotly(gg2)
  p2
})
```

But when I do just normal ggplot2, the tabPanel works fine:

`ui.R`

```
       tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                   id = "tabset1",
                   tabPanel("Rate", value = "Rate", plotOutput("ratePlot")),
                   tabPanel("Mass", value = "Mass", plotOutput("massPlot"))#, plotlyOutput("massPlot"))
                  )
```

`server.R`

```
output$ratePlot <- renderPlot({ #ly
  gg <- ggplot(result(), aes(x = Name, y = Rate, fill = Name)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 1)
  gg
  #p <- ggplotly(gg)
  #p
})

output$massPlot <- renderPlot({
  gg2 <- ggplot(result(), aes(x = Name, y = Mass, fill = Name)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    scale_fill_brewer(type = "qual", palette = 1)
  gg2
})
```

Is there some functionality that I need to change?

Comment: in your first output$massPlot p2 is not printed

Comment: oops, sorry, I forgot to put that on this code line, i will edit to reflect that change.

Comment: I have yet to use ggplotly with shiny but aren't you supposed to have a usename or password to use plotly?

Comment: @MLavoie Think changed now open source

Comment: @Alex would help to have some data. Have you tried just outputting the  plotlyOutput("ratePlot")  plotlyOutput("massPlot") without any of the tabset panel/panel/column . Could help identify problem area

Comment: yeah, I will put the data up. I do have a username and password but those you package within to the tool on startup with the package, you set it once and you're done.

Comment: @pssguy great suggestion. I have tried outputting the plotlyOuput, but it unfortunately didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: No joy, I'm afraid. If i replace  if(state == "")  with if(is.null(state) I do get the plotly version of ratePlot showing up inc in the tab version but not the massPlot -even when I comment out ratePlot code which is strange but may be down to a beer or two. You might want to try the plot_ly function as an alternative

Comment: @pssguy :/ okay thanks, I appreciate it. I think it might be a bug with the `plotly` package or there's something behind the scenes with allocation that only allows the use of 1. yeah i'll try just plot_ly next instead of ggplotly integration

Answer (score 0):

For now, it seems as there is no solution to using tabbed panels with `ggplot2` integration within plotly (`ggplotly()`). Worked around this issue by just using `plotly()` for each graph between the tabs.